# What algorithm is used by the $geowithin operator of Mongodb

Tags: geometry, algorithm, mongodb, within

MongoDB can perform geospatial query such as finding restaurants inside region with the operator $geowithin. For example:

```
db.places.find(
   {
     loc: {
       $geoWithin: {
          $geometry: {
             type : "Polygon" ,
             coordinates: [ [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 3, 6 ], [ 6, 1 ], [ 0, 0 ] ] ]
          }
       }
     }
   }
)
```

I would like to know which algorithm is used by the operator $geoWithin of MongoDB. Can someone provide the pseudo-code?

Comment: Since MongoDB is open source, you can do better than pseudo-code if you do a little digging. Point-in-polygon only has one basic implementation.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/geo/geometry_container.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a point-in-polygon intersection test, it appears to use the raycasting method.

The source of MongoDB is available [here on GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/geo/shapes.cpp) - look for Polygon::contains .

Wikipedia has a [good writeup of the raycasting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)